# what will happen to the data if a crash occurs when using fdatasync() in aof?

Tags: redis

i'v been reading redis source code recently, i found that in flushAppendOnlyFile() the writer uses fdatasync to update data to disk.
as we know, fdatasync() doesn't write metadata info, and flushAppendOnlyFile() will change the aof file size. so if a crash occurs before system update the metadata, will the newest aof data be lost?
the writer wrote below in http://oldblog.antirez.com/post/fsync-different-thread-useless.html

> I can avoid synching metadata without problems, but if I understand this correctly, in an append only file context, not synching the size seems equivalent to leaking data if a crash occurs I guess... so this is not possible in my context.

which i don't understand why it's not possible in the redis context.
could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

That's not what he's saying. `fdatasync` *does* update the metadata of the file if the size has changed, as noted by the commenter "kosaki" that Salvatore was responding to, and as noted by the manual which says

> fdatasync() is similar to fsync(), but it does not flush modified metadata *unless that metadata is needed in order to allow a subsequent data retrieval* to be correctly handled

(emphasis mine). So there is no data loss when using `fdatasync` to sync the AOF.

What kosaki is suggesting is a different method of syncing that would indeed never sync metadata, and Salvatore is pointing out that that *would* lose data in the event of a crash. What is "impossible" is using that alternative *instead* of `fdatasync`.